# Mistake in paper? Subgroup of order $4$ in group of order $16$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm reading this proof from this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-007-9067-6) and I don't see why one argument works. In the Lemma, $n_4(G)$ is the number of elements of order $4$ in $G$.

In the first step of the induction we have a group $G$ with $|G|=16$ and $exp(G)=4$, three maximal subgroups $A,B,C \leq G$, s.t. $A \cap B \cap C =H$ with $|H|=4$.

Now the author says, that if $C_G(H)=G$, then $G$ is abelian.
I don't see, why this is true and I think I found a counterexample:

I looked up $SmallGroup(16,3)=C_2^2 \rtimes C_4$ in which exist three maximal subgroups with intersection $H=Z(G) \cong C_2^2$. Clearly $C_G(H)=G$, but $G$ is not abelian. What am I missing?

[SmallGroup(16,3)](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/1/C2%5E2sC4.html)

[image: Lemma 9]

**Edit:**
I think the next argument is wrong aswell. If $C_G(H)\not = G$, then $C_G(H)=A$ is indeed abelian, but its not true, that $B\cong C$. See $SmallGroup(16,13)$ and chose $Q_8$ as a maximal subgroup. It will always lead to $(A,B,C)=(C_4 \times C_2,Q_8,D_8)$ (up to ordering). Is there any quick way to see that all groups of order $16$ contain a number of elements of order 4, that is divisible by $4$?

Comment: Since the action of $C_4$ on $H$ is non-trivial, $C_4$ cannot be contained in $C_G(H$)

Comment: I agree, this statement seems to be wrong. In fact there are three counterexamples, $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(16,k)$ for $k=3,4$ and  $6$. But since these groups have $8$, $12$ and $4$ elements of order $4$, the result seems to be correct.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed the statement is true anyway, as the inductive step works. Then I try to find an argument for myself.

Comment: After thinking some time, I think the next argument is wrong aswell. If $C_G(H)\not = G$, then $C_G(H)=A$ is indeed abelian, but its not true, that $B\cong C$. See $SmallGroup(16,13)$ and chose $Q_8$ as a maximal subgroup. It will always lead to $(A,B,C)=(C_4 \times C_2,Q_8,D_8)$ (up to ordering). Is there any quick way to see that all groups of order $16$ contain a number of elements of order 4, that is divisible by $4$?

Comment: Arguably, the quickest and easiest way of doing this (and also the most reliable and likely to be accurate) is just to check it on the computer for each of the 7 groups of order 16 that have exponent 4.

Comment: This result has got to be somewhere in some volume of Berkovich's and Janko's "Groups of Prime Power Order". In any case, I strongly doubt that it is new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the parts of the proof which you rightly question aren't actually necessary.

We have $n_4(G)\equiv n_4(A)+n_4(B)+n_4(C)\pmod 4$. Since $C_G(H)\ne H$ we can suppose $A$ is abelian and therefore $n_4(A)\equiv 0\pmod 4$.

**If both $B$ and $C$ are non-abelian**

Then  $n_4(B)\equiv n_4(C)\equiv 2\pmod 4$ and we are finished.

**If, say, $B$ is abelian**

Then $G=<A,B>\leq C(H)$ and so $C$ is also abelian. Then  $n_4(B)\equiv n_4(C)\equiv 0\pmod 4$ and we are finished.